# Ordering results by field using Orion NGSI-LD

Tags: fiware-orion

I would like to know if it is posible to order results by field in Orion NGSI-LD, using orderBy param.
This functionality is already implemented in Orion NGSIv2 (https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/orion-api.html#ordering-results).

I have tried to use orderBy param in GET http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities?type=Incident&options=keyValues&orderBy=!code but it does not seem to work.

However, if the search is performed using entity id as orderBy value, it works, GET http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities?type=Incident&options=keyValues&orderBy=id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, sorry. That "orderBy" URL param is strictly NGSIv2.  NGSI-LD doesn't (currently) support any ordering. It's not standardized and up to the implementations.  Orion-LD orders the response by "createdAt", as this makes pagination easier. NOTE that it's not ordered by Entity ID.
That said, we could include this new feature in the NGSI-LD standard. I'm part of the ETSI ISG CIM group that defines the NGSI-LD API and I'll take this up in our next meeting (Tuesday, Jan 17).

Comment: I would like to ask you, after ETSI ISG CIM meeging, if you have considered including ordering feature in the NGSI-LD standard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, we are definitely considering it.  Details will need to be discussed and defined but it really seems it will be accepted in the standard.

Comment: I have just tested it on orion-ld:1.5.0-PRE-1526 and I can see the "orderBy" fetaure has been implemented. (even if I can't see it in the NGSI-LD spec : V1.7.1 from 2023-06)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Orion-LD, for now, orders the entities by the createdAt builtin timestamp. Anything you've seen about 'orderBy', that's probably from NGSIv2. Not implemented in NGSI-LD. Sorry, this feature is still not implemented, mainly as it is pretty much impossible to order entities on anything else than createdAt in a distributed environment, so, don't hold your breath ... sorry